# Changing language keyboard layout via XML

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-layout

The xml below adds The language Portuguese Brazil (Brazil ABNT)

That is my keyboard is now set to work with the Portuguese language and using the keyboard layout called Brazil ABNT.

What I need is Language Portuguese Brazil, but using a keyboard layout called US International

The first image shows what the xml does(notice the Brazil ABNT next to keyboard layout)
http://imageshack.com/a/img540/5873/kRNRKW.jpg

The second image I went ahead and added a second keyboard layout, us-International
http://imageshack.com/a/img743/9076/zAi0KD.jpg

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend"> 
<gs:UserList>
<gs:User UserID="Current" CopySettingsToDefaultUserAcct="true" CopySettingsToSystemAcct="true"/>    </gs:UserList> 
<gs:InputPreferences> 

<!--ch-Google--><gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0416:00000416" />

</gs:InputPreferences>
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 8.1

Comment: Your question does not make sense

Comment: Hi RafaelBarriola. Super User, and Stack Exchange in general, works best when questions are *explicit* and *specific* about what the asker wants to know. I recommend that you **[edit]** this question to add *a specific question,* so that we are not forced to guess (which usually ends poorly). For the moment your question appears to be attracting close votes as "unclear what you are asking", almost certainly for this exact reason. It *might* also be a good idea to include the command for how this XML file is intended to be used; I don't know, but it might make a difference, and it won't hurt.

Comment: I changed a bit and also added a few reference pictures to illustrate what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, after hours of trying to find the solution I did find it. All I have to do is change the ID="0416:00020409" the first part of the ID being the 0416 is the language and the second part 00020409 specifies windows to use keyboard layout US-International, my ID before was always doing ABNT layout.

Credit to Kristian help me find the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is what you're looking for:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/change-keyboard-layout

If not, then I haven't understood your question. Sorry!

Comment: something like that, but I would like to do that when I ran the script on the XML file, to do a unattended installation.

Comment: I see what you meant now.
I believe you need to modify your string (i.e. "0416:00000416") to be 0416:00020409 or something along those lines.

See this blog post for details:
http://blog.compower.org/2013/09/09/manage-keyboard-layouts-unattended/

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Sorry Kristian we both posted at around the same time, because of you I saw how to get what I want, the credit is all yours.

Comment: Glad I could help!